# use GETPIVOTDATA to get specific grandtotals

Tags: excel, vba

The forum has been great so far - thanks for everything you do.

So I've generated a PivotTable and need to retrieve the grand total associated with the last row item in the PivotTable using VBA.  What I have currently gets me month-specific data, but once we add more months, the code will be useless:

[image]

Code:

```
  Worksheets("Spend Analysis 2").Activate
  Dim CurrentMonthSpend As Range
  Range("A3").Select
  Set CurrentMonthSpend = ActiveCell. _
   PivotTable.GetPivotData("All Costs", "Month", "June")
  Dim PreviousMonthSpend As Range
  Set PreviousMonthSpend = ActiveCell. _
   PivotTable.GetPivotData("All Costs", "Month", "May")
```

Is there a way to always get the grand total associated with the last item in the row?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Taimur_Khan have you tried a Loop to get the last value?  Alternately, there are filters in the pivot table that allow you to limit to specific time periods - would any of them work along with a simple GETPIVOTDATA formula?